# android sqlite statement with integer inside Values

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to write an SQL statement which binds an integer inside its parameter values. The value of column `COLUMN_PRIORITY` is `10`. How do I put it inside the query?

```
SQLiteStatement sqLiteStatement = db.compileStatement("" + "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
               COLUMN_ID + ", " +
               COLUMN_TITLE + ", " +
               COLUMN_PRIORITY + ", " +
               COLUMN_CREATED_AT + ", " +
               COLUMN_UPDATED_AT + ") " +
                "Values ( ?,?," +
                  10 + ", " +
                createdAt + ", " + updatedAt") " ) ;

        sqLiteStatement.bindString(1, contextId);
        sqLiteStatement.bindString(2, bubbleDetails.getId());
        sqLiteStatement.execute();
```

This statement is not valid. I have no idea how to fix it

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Before invoking the method compileStatement, print the string being passed to it. Something might stand out.

Comment: I've printed the string and it looks fine for me. The problem is that inside "Values ( ?,?," +
                  10 + ", " +
                createdAt + ", " + updatedAt") " it doesn'r expect to get varaibles and integer values, it expects to get question marks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `db.insert` method that accepts a `ContentValues` object.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(COLUMN_PRIORITY, 10);
//... Other columns 
db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the workaround that I used. I just wonder if there is a way to do it without content values

Comment: It isn't a "workaround" at all. IMO, it is the recommended approach to prevent SQL Injection. And I don't see the `bindString` method that accepts an `int`value anyways, so I think you would have needed to use `bindString(x, String.valueOf(id))`, for example.